# Use linux commands in Docker file and build on windows

Tags: linux, windows, docker, dockerfile, docker-build

I am a beginner in Docker and I have a situation here.
My docker file looks like this.

```
FROM python:3.6-alpine

#Copy contents
COPY . /srv/flask_app
WORKDIR /srv/flask_app

#Get essentials to base image
RUN apt-get clean \
    && apt-get -y update

RUN apt-get -y install nginx \
    && apt-get -y install python3-dev \
    && apt-get -y install build-essential

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt --src /usr/local/src

COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx
RUN chmod +x ./start.sh

CMD ["./start.sh"]
```

When I am trying to build the docker file on windows, it is giving me an error saying the Linux command can't be found. How can I build a docker specific to Linux, on windows?

Comment: Try to enable Linux container from the docker setting then try to run

Comment: "an error saying the Linux command can't be found" - can you specify what error you see?

Comment: @viraptor The error I am getting is "/bin/sh: apt-get: not found"

Comment: @Adiii - Can you please help me how to enable that on windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are on `alpine` , you should use `apk` not `apt-get` .

`apt-get` is the package management for `Debian` baised systems.

you can also change the base image then do not need to change any commands:

```
FROM python:3.6-buster
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked :) I was experimenting with the python containers and got stuck with this.